# file directory not found in different python packages

Tags: python, directory, init, file-not-found

i have project where its structure looks something like this:

```
Foo
|- init.py
|- xml_folder
|  - file1.xml
|- bar.py
|- tests #contains TDDs
|  - test1.py
```

in bar.py I'm appending the list of files in xml_folder in a list:

```
file_list = os.listdir("xml_folder")
```

and I am trying to test the list is not empty by calling it in test1.py and checking the list's size this worked perfectly when using the absolute path, but now that I am using the relative path it does not work (and I have to use the relative path for publishing purposes)

the Error is thrown when calling the method that appends the list in bar.py by test1.py

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] no such file or directory: 'xml_folder'

what should I do to resolve this ??

Comment: Did you try changing the current directory using `os.chdir( )` before using `os.listdir( )`

Comment: I think he just have `test1.py` in other directory, he simply should join path of file and folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pathlib` module of python for filesystem related things.

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Below line will give you the path to the xml_folder one level up

xml_folder = Path(__file__).absolute().parents[1] / Path('xml_folder')

# Get the file name of that folder

file_list = xml_folder.glob("**/*")
```